# Manually call __init__

Tags: python, class, tkinter, window

So I'm trying to handle two windows in python tkinter that can edit an xml file containing the path to certain images, the problem is the function that reads the file is in the `__init__` of my two class windows so whenever I switch between the windows the same images appear. My question is: is there any way to relaunch the classes so that the `__init__` will run?

I believe the problem is within the `show_frame` function since `tkraise` does not run the functions in the class but just pops whatever is in the class to the top.

```
class xmleditApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (FirstWindow, SecondWindow):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(FirstWindow)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
```

This is the class that I want to update automatically when I return to it:

```
class FirstWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        secondwindow=tk.Button(self,text="edit xml",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SecondWindow))
        secondwindow.grid(row=3,column=0)

        def getimagepath():
            doc = parse('pruebasXML.xml')
            paths = doc.getroot()
            path = paths.findall('path')
            pasthlist = []
            for elem in range (0,len(path)):
                pathlist+=[[]]
                for tag in range (0,11):
                    pathlist[elem]+=[path[elem][tag].text]
            return createbutton(pasthlist)

        def createbutton(lst):
            for elem in range(0,len(lst)):
                buttonName=elem
                photo=tk.PhotoImage(file=lst[elem][0]+'.gif')
                buttonName=tk.Button(self, image=photo)
                buttonName.grid(row=2, column=elem)
                buttonName.image=photo

        if os.path.exists('pathsXML.xml')==True:
            getimagepath()
```

Comment: is that safe? ive heard of a lot of problems going on when calling __init__ also I would I need to write the parent and controler in the parenthesis? @fhdrsdg

Comment: Why don't you just move the logic out of `__init__` instead?

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes

Comment: when I move it out of the __init__ I get an error saying createbutton doesn't exist

Comment: When you define `createbutton` at the same level as `__init__`, you should define it as `def createbutton(self, lst):` and call it as `self.createbutton(some_list)`

Comment: I've tried that but got an error saying self is not defined

Comment: Then you need to keep working on it until that's fixed.

Comment: yep i'll try to leave the logic in the __init __ and call the __init __ from show_frame. Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: That's not a great idea, but have fun.

Comment: How do you figure? Maybe restart the GUI?

Comment: Why are you creating functions inside of `__init__`? There's no reason to do that, and obviously it's causing you problems. Make them normal class methods that accept an argument for the filename, rather than hard-coding the file name.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a class called `myclass`, you can manually call `__init__` by using `myclass.__init__(self, etc)`. Here, `self` is the self argument, and `etc` are the other arguments.